# Checking if Username Exists in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsuserdefaults

I currently want to check if a username exists in NSUserDefaults, if it does not I want to load a modal view controller. The problem is that even though the username is nil, it's still acting as if it exists. Here's what I have:

```
//Check if the login data exists
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] != nil) {

        //Load Login View if no username is found
        NSLog(@"No username found");
        LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else {

        NSString *savedUsername = [defaults stringForKey:@"username"];
        NSLog(@"Username found: %@", savedUsername);

    }
```

I keep getting this in my NSLog: *`Username found: (null)`*

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if (![default objectForKey:@"Username"])

Comment: Are you by any chance setting `[NSNull null]` as username in userDefaults?

Comment: @BuntyMadan Please enter that as the answer, since you wrote it first and it worked. Makes so much sense.

Comment: you should enter : if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil), because you want to test if it already exists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try this no need to use `nil`.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![defaults objectForKey:@"Username"]) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: All of you i do't want to write the answer as just 1 hint was enough that's why i wrote comment First By the way all are best and bright so good luck Young mans..!

Answer (score 10):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil) {

        //Load Login View if no username is found
        NSLog(@"No username found");
        LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else {

        NSString *savedUsername = [defaults stringForKey:@"username"];
        NSLog(@"Username found: %@", savedUsername);

    }
```

Comment: it does! see the requirement.

Comment: did you try this @art-divin ?

Comment: yeah, his wrong check mislead me, your answer is the correct one

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( ! [defaults objectForKey:@"username"] )
```

Comment: also doesn't make any sense. Nil and NULL are almost the same except that NULL should be used for C++ code in objc environment, and nil should be used for objc objects.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `!= nil` which is the opposite of what you want. Change your first if statement to:

```
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil) {
```

Or just:

```
if (![defaults objectForKey:@"username"]) {
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **delete the app** from your phone/simulator

[image]

**Replace the code** with this, and run

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil) {

        //Load Login View if no username is found
        NSLog(@"No username found");

        //set the username,
       [defaults setObject:@"username_1" forKey:@"username"];

        LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else {

        NSString *savedUsername = [defaults stringForKey:@"username"];
        NSLog(@"Username found: %@", savedUsername);

    }
```

**Good To Know**: 
Once you save an object for key "username", later
this condition always returns false,

```
([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil)
```

If you delete the previous installation. The UserDefaults automatically gets deleted.
then only you can try whether this is working **([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil)**

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, your test

```
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] != nil)
```

is wrong. But even with

```
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil)
```

you have a problem if the user defaults contain a value for "username" that is ***not a string***. In that case `objectforKey` returns a value, but `stringForKey` returns `nil`.

Therefore, you should use ***only*** `stringForKey`:

```
NSString *savedUsername = [defaults stringForKey:@"username"];
if (savedUsername == nil) {
    //Load Login View if no username is found
    NSLog(@"No username found");
    // ...
} else {
    NSLog(@"Username found: %@", savedUsername);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are confused in NULL and NIL ,You can also use this approach:-

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString*value=[prefs objectForKey:@"username"];

NSLog(@"useremail %@",value);

value=[value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

if ([value length]>0)
{


      NSString *savedUsername = [defaults stringForKey:@"username"];
    NSLog(@"Username found: %@", savedUsername);

}

else {

    NSLog(@"No username found");
    LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil]; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
NSUserDefaults *Def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![Def objectForKey:@"Username"]) 
    {
       // Code 
    } 
    else
    {
       //Code
    }
```

this will really help you.